# Finding extremes and values between them for a graph

Tags: javascript, graph

I need an algorithm to find extremes and a certain number of values between them for a graph. For example, the highest value I have is 0.805 and the lowest is 0.694; I want the extremes to be 0.81 and 0.69; given that the number of values in between is 6, I want these values to be 0.79, 0.78, 0.76, 0.74, 0.72, 0.71 or so.

Long ago I wrote a function that finds the high extreme, but it was intended for the graphs with the lowest value is always set to 0:

```
const BASE = 5;
const LENGTH = 2;

function graphTopValue(max_value, max_items) {
  return restore(find(extract(max_value), max_items), max_value);
}

function numlen(n) {
  return Math.ceil(Math.log10(n));
}

function isDivisible(v, i) {
  var r = numlen(v) - 1;
  if ([0, 3, 6, 9].includes(r)) return true;
  return (v / i) % BASE == 0;
}

function extract(v) {
  return parseInt(v.toString().substr(0, LENGTH)) + 1;
}

function restore(v, o) {
  var oldlen = numlen(o);
  if (oldlen <= LENGTH) return v;
  return v * Math.pow(10, oldlen - LENGTH);
}

function find(v, i) {
  if (v % i == 0 && isDivisible(v, i)) return v;
  return find(v + i - (v % i), i);
}

var max_value = 999;
var max_items = 4;
console.log(graphTopValue(max_value, max_items)); // 1000
```

Now I need an algorithm to work with any values and also find pretty values between extremes. How can I do it?

Comment: Your question is somewhat ill-defined. Can I assume that you always want to round the values to two decimals?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware No. For example, if the highest value is 999, the lowest is 0, and the number of values to find in between is 3, I want the extremes to be 1000 and 0, and the values in between to be 250, 500 and 750.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've found out that this is called 'Nice Label Algorithm'. Here's one of implementations:

https://gist.github.com/igodorogea/4f42a95ea31414c3a755a8b202676dfd